# htaccess redirect not working - tweak needed

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect

i have a little issue that some of you may be able to sort please

in my htaccess i have

RewriteRule apply /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]

basically meaning any get requests to apply will be sent on

however i have a page apply.html which with the above is no longer accessible as it creates a redirect loop

anyone know how to change the htaccess declaration so as only apply (and not apply.html) forwards on ?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a rewrite condition as well as limiting the matching pattern in the regex:

The condition will make sure that the rule will only be applied if the request isn't for an existing file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^apply$ /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks just a tweak of the above worked `code`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^apply$ /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]`code`